# Is a bridge a half or full duplex device?

Tags: cisco

Is a bridge a half or full duplex device?

Comment: Are you asking about a wireless bridge (IEEE 802.11 / WiFi), or are you asking about a wired bridge?

Comment: gotta downvote bcs your question is unclear.  wired or wireless?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a bridge a half or full duplex device?

That depends on how the interfaces are configured and used. On a bridge (or a switch, which is a type of bridge), each interface is its own collision domain.

If there is only one device connected to the interface, and that device supports full duplex, then the bridge can run that interface in full duplex if the single device does because there are no possibilities for collisions.

If there are multiple device connected to that one interface, then there may be collisions, so the bridge interface must run in half duplex.

Inside the bridge itself, there are no collisions, so frames can travel between the different ports simultaneously. In one sense, that may be called full duplex, but each bridge interface has its duplex set independently of how the other interfaces are set. Some could be full duplex, and some could be half duplex.

Comment: I don't understand how multiple devices are connected on single switch port/interface?

Comment: That is what a hub can do. A hub is basically a powered cable because it repeats all signals received on any interface to all the other interfaces, and that can lead to collisions. If a switch is connected to one of the hub interfaces, you have all the devices connected to the other hub interfaces effectively connected to the single switch interface.

Comment: you should write one networking book of all basic concepts. Then all students like me all over the world will be benefited.

Answer (score -1):

> While the wired Ethernet side can be full-duplex, the radio side is
>   not.

[Troubleshoot Common Problems with Wireless Bridged Networks, cisco.com](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/wireless-lan-wlan/22950-br-ts-22950.html)

The 802.11 family consists of a series of half-duplex over-the-air modulation techniques that use the same basic protocol.

[IEEE 802.11 WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)

Comment: What's inaccurate about this answer?  I'd like to know.